# Where to handle returning data from Angular service?

Tags: angularjs, service

I try to handle an Angularjs 1 project by using classes, I have created class as the following

```
angular.module('Models').factory('Project', function (API, $rootScope) {

var Project = function() {
    return new Project.fn.init();
}

// instance methods
Project.fn = Project.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.id = null,
        this.name = ""
    },

    setId: function(id) {
        this.id = id;
    },
    setName: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },...
```

Now I set the obj attr. in the same class as following:

```
Project.getAll = function(scopeProjects) {

    return API.getAll(this).then(function(response) {

        var allProjects = response.data.body;
        allProjects.forEach(function (project) {
            var obj = new Project();
            obj.setId(project.id);
            obj.setName(project.name);
            scopeProjects.push(obj);
        })

    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Fail : ", error);
    });
}
```

**my question is where to use my setters?**
Do I have to handle this by returning the data to controllers or the way I use here is the best one?

Comment: MVC usually has the controller do as little as possible, meaning it should probably not be done there.

Comment: The jquery `fn` is not available for `Project` as in `Project.fn`. Simply use ` Project.prototype = ` then you can use `obj.setName` etc.